# How to fix Google cloud deployment error: xxxxx.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com"; builder service account does not have access to the bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am deploying a simple golang demo project in GCP.

I have already enabled App Engine Admin and Compute Instance Admin.
app.yaml:

```
runtime: go116
```

After I ran `gcloud app deploy`, error shows：

```
RROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Failed to create cloud build: invalid bucket "xxxxx.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com"; builder service account does not have access to the bucket
com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcClientException: <eye3 title='/ArgoAdminV1.CreateBuild, INVALID_ARGUMENT'/> APPLICATION_ERROR;google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1/ArgoAdminV1.CreateBuild;invalid bucket "803210166573.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com"; builder service account does not have access to the bucket;AppErrorCode=3;StartTimeMs=1639637376387;unknown;ResFormat=AUTOMATIC;ServerTimeSec=1.026818102;LogBytes=256;Non-FailFast;EndUserCredsRequested;EffSecLevel=none;ReqFormat=AUTOMATIC;ReqID=7d291fd45204c21b;GlobalID=0;Server=[2002:a17:512:234c:b0:42e:8669:5870]:4001.
```

How could I fix this error?

Comment: In the error message note **invalid bucket**. Did you misspell the bucket name? Or a syntax error in the deployment command/files? Edit your question and show the command and deployment files.

Comment: so I add app.yaml in my question? It only has  one line: runtime: go116

Comment: Make sure the bucket name is correct and the service account has been granted Storage Admin role as outlined [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs#store-custom-bucket).

Comment: I am having the same issue, with a Node.js project. Invalid bucket seems to be a bit of a red herring, given that it's a Google managed bucket. Have tried granting App Engine Admin and Storage Admin roles to the Cloud Build service account to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this working by re-authenticating `gcloud auth login`.

Odd, as it was working fine with a different project, but maybe that will fix it for you.